# In Spring MVC are global variables in an action available to every user

Tags: java, spring, struts

I am using Spring and Struts

If I create a global variable in my action class which has logged in user ID in it. Does it mean this variable will change to hold the last logged in user ID, or is it going to be different for each user on my server?

Does spring/struts create only one instance of the action class which all users use or is it a new object for each user on the website?

Comment: What is a "global" variable? If you use static, it is the same for every instance of the object, so it makes no difference if there is a new instance.

Comment: Which version of Struts? It's important to differentiate since they're radically different. It's also completely unclear what you mean by "global" variable.